# DSP - Group Delay of an IIR filter

Tags: filter, signal-processing

I need to write a program in order to filter a signal for 0.8-3 Hz. Even though I have a working FIR filter this one takes too long and I've decided to change to an IIR filter. I've designed one myself using fdatool in Matlab and I've got the NUM and DEN. The improvement in time would be quite good (the FIR was 125 taps and this one's order is 12).
The next step was to move to the C implementation and I've found this nice website http://iowahills.com/Example%20Code/IIRNthOrderImplementation.txt .

The problem is that in their code there is a parameter I just don't understand and that is NumSigPts.

```
void RunIIRPoly( double *Signal, double *FilteredSignal, int NumSigPts)
{
 int j, k, N;
 double y, Reg[100];

 for(j=0; j<100; j++)Reg[j] = 0.0; // Init the delay registers.

 for(j=0; j<NumSigPts; j++)
 {
  // Shift the delay register values.
  for(k=N; k>0; k--)Reg[k] = Reg[k-1];

  // The denominator
  Reg[0] = Signal[j];
  for(k=1; k<=N; k++)Reg[0] -= DenomCoeff[k] * Reg[k];

  // The numerator
  y = 0;
  for(k=0; k<=N; k++)y += NumCoeff[k] * Reg[k];
  FilteredSignal[j] = y;
 }

}
```

In the description they say

> This particular filter has a nominal group delay of 4 so we set
>   NumSigPts to at least 1000 + 2*4

How can I find the group delay of my filter. Does it have anything to do with the filter's order?
The signal I filter is continuously provided so my exact question would be what is the minimum size of the signal in order to begin filtering?

Later edit:

So today I had some attempts with this IIR filter, but still haven't managed to get some good results.
I took Nate's advice and tried Matlab's grpdelay function. The thing is I'm not quite sure how interpret the output.
[image: grpdelay]

What I'm trying to do is to filter some images,frames, pixel by pixel. The way I'm doing this is to store the images in a array of images which is all_frames. To access each pixel I call all_frames[frame_number][pixel_number].

The code I came up with following the website mention above is:

```
void ApplyIIR ( float **all_frames, float *num, float *den, int frame_number,  float *filter_Xs, int w, int h)
{   
        float Reg[FILTER_ORDER];

    for (int i=0; i< (width*height) ; i++) {  //go pixel by pixel

        for(int j=0; j<FILTER_ORDER; j++) //init regs
                Reg[j] = 0.0;
        float final_X=0;

            for(int l=0; l< FILTER_ORDER+ DELAY ; l++) {  // not sure how to set DELAY

                    for(int k=FILTER_ORDER-1; k>0;k--)
                        Reg[k] = Reg[k-1];

                    Reg[0] = all_frames[frame_number][i]; //get pixels one by one
                    for(int k=1; k<FILTER_ORDER;k++)
                        Reg[0] -= den[k]* Reg[k];


                    for(int k=0;k<FILTER_ORDER;k++)
                        final_X += num[k] * Reg[k];

                    if(frame_number == 0)             //go through all the frames
                        frame_number = FILTER_ORDER - 1;
                    else
                        frame_number--;

                }
                    filter_Xs[i] = final_X;         
    }

}
```

FILTER_ORDER is set to 13, since num and den have 0-12 values.

Am I on a completely wrong path?

Comment: Woah, wait, did you try your filter in Matlab first? I didn't realize you were filtering an image. Filtering images with IIR filters can be a mess, please double check that your filter works on images before you bother implementing it in C.

Answer (score 2):

The key is this comment:

> Remember that these filters have delay, so you need to run the code
>   for M points longer than the number of data points to be filtered in
>   order to get the entire signal through the filter. A reasonable
>   value for M is twice the group delay value.

As the example code says, any IIR filter will have delay. This occurs because the filter continues responding after the signal has passed through. This means your loop needs to be `Length of Signal` + `Length of M` in order to process the signal completely. `NumSigPoints` is this value, and basically tells the filter how long to process for.

I *think* what they mean by nominal group delay is the maximum group delay value of the filter. Group delay is basically how much a frequency passing through the filter will be delayed, and it's a function of frequency (IIR filters have non-linear group delay). You can calculate the maximum group delay of your filter, or you can just eyeball it so that you process the entire signal. If you have Matlab, try using the [grpdelay](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/grpdelay.html) function.

If this is a continuous process you're going to need to filter in blocks as the signal comes in. The minimum size of the signal will be a function of the size of your window (block size), which you can pick yourself. You may want to look for implementations of real time filtering, because windowing itself (window type, overlap, etc) is the subject of at least a few lectures of an undergrad DSP class.

Comment: Hi Nate, thanks for your answer. I've tried your advice with grpdelay and I've updated my question. I understand that I have to divide the signal in blocks, but this is exactly my concern, the minimum size of a block. I've assumed that it has to be at least the same size as the filter order. Or is that something just for FIR filters? Also I've followed the registers and from my understanding even after the first value of the signal enters the registers, it will produce a value at the output. Isn't that right?

Comment: I'll +1 this since no one else seems to have... and it answered the _actual_ question, before it was edited with something else that should've been a separate question... _if_ it was actually asking anything. bad case of moving goalposts imho